# How to apply .gitignore to previous commit history?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I have a private repository which has never been published. My current `.gitignore` excludes many junk files which I previously forgot to exclude, and I would like these junk files to disappear from my git history. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8112372/2024042 explains how to remove a single file `bin` from the git history, but can I apply the entire rules of `.gitignore` to all commits in the past, without manually enumerating each individual file?

See also [Completely remove file from all Git repository commit history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/completely-remove-file-from-all-git-repository-commit-history) for removing individual files.

Comment: While `.gitignore` will be deleted whenever Git checkouts an older commit, `.git/info/exclude` (essentially an untracked "`.gitingore`" file) can keep ignoring files while doing any Git operation. The question would remain as how rewrite a commit to untrack every ignored file, so you can use it with `filter-branch`.